# database value how to pass dropdown list in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to pass value to drop down list in CodeIgniter?

This is my view file HTML code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <select name="department" id ="department">
                <?php
                    foreach($dept as $country)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$country['dept_id'].'">'.$country['managers_name'].'</option>';
                    }
                ?>

            </select>
        </div>
```

This is my controller code:

```
    public function department()
    {
        $this->load->model('insert_model');
        $data['dept'] = $this->insert_model->category_name_get();

    }
```

This is my model file code:

```
    function category_name_get()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('dept');
        if ($query->num_rows >= 1)
        {
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                $data[$row['dept_id']]=$row['managers_name'];
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: @raja, do you want to get names of department from database and create a dropdown list from it ? is that what you need?

Comment: I need names of department from database ,and pass drop down list in view page how .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for **Adding Dynamic Data to the View**

Data is passed from the controller to the view by way of an array or an object in the second parameter of the view loading method. Here is an example using an array:

```
$data = array(
        'title' => 'My Title',
        'heading' => 'My Heading',
        'message' => 'My Message'
);

$this->load->view('blogview', $data);
```

In your case `$data` contains the department list in it as an array.

Comment: your explanation is right but the question isn't , first I can't see loading a view in his controller and secondly what is happening in model makes no sense.

Comment: i'm a new in codeigniter,so i con't understand this example kindly elaborate this example

Answer (score 0):

In Your COntroller file you will get all date on $data['dept'] that returned from model.

```
public function department()
{
    $this->load->model('insert_model');
    $data['dept'] = $this->insert_model->category_name_get();
    $this->load->view('view_file_name',$data);
}
```

In your view file you will get this data
Just do `print_r($dept);` and check array..

you will find more info from this [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Comment: i used same but it is not loading in view file .

Answer (score 0):

Probably your model is not returning "proper" data for your view. Perhaps something like this:

```
function category_name_get()
{
    $data   = array();
    $query  = $this->db->get('dept');
    if ($query->num_rows >= 1)
    {
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = array(
                'dept_id'       => $row['dept_id'],
                'managers_name' => $row['managers_name']
            );
        }            
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function category_name_get()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('dept');
        if ($query->num_rows() >= 1)
        {
            foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
            {
                $data[$row['dept_id']]=$row['managers_name'];
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

Use num_rows() instead of num_rows. I hope it works now.